# Update table with math operations on values from the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to update table cells with results of math operations on values from the same table. Below you can see my table (this is a result for a specified user ID):

```
===================================
 DATE     | AMOUNT |  DIR  | AFTER
===================================
 02-07-17 |   8    |   1   |   50
 01-07-17 |   3    |   0   |   42
 28-06-17 |   3    |   0   |   45
 14-11-15 |   8    |   1   |    0
 24-06-15 |   3    |   0   |    0
 22-05-15 |   3    |   0   |    0
===================================
```

First column is a date of operation (table shows values of specified user ID with "ORDER BY date DESC" order). 2nd column (called AMOUNT) is a value of points given to (or taken from) a specified user's account (this column has an UNSIGNED attribute so it cannot take negative values). 3rd column (called DIR) is a binary value of operation direction (0 = taken from, 1 = given to). And last column (called AFTER) indicates the current points values after each operation. This shows that on 28th June the user had 45 points. On 1st July he lost 3 points and AFTER value on that day has been set to 42 (45-3=42). On 2nd July he has received 8 points and the current account value is 50 (42+8=50).
As you can see, only first 3 rows of AFTER column have a values - this is because the script, which I have created a year ago, did not store these values until 1st June this year (there was even no column called AFTER). Since 1st June, I'm forced to store those values in the DB and this is working, but previous records (before I've made changes) do not have a proper values of points after operations before 1st June 2017 (they have just zeros). So I need to update a table using some piece of php + mysql code (which will be executed manually as "sync points" option, once per user) to keep all the "points after" values correct for every user.

I think I need to:
1. get the most recent (by date) AMOUNT and AFTER values of a specified user ID,
2. add or substract AMOUNT to/from AFTER value (depends of DIR),
3. update 2ND ROW with new value of AFTER (there is a value stored but it can be overwritten as it should be the same),
4. get the 2ND ROW's AMOUNT and AFTER,
5. add or substract AMOUNT to/from AFTER value (depends of DIR),
6. update 3RD ROW with new value of AFTER,
7. etc... etc... (do it all in a loop until the last record is updated).

Could you please help me with a correct MySQL query or queries to make it work?

Comment: you need to fix the formatting

Comment: "get the last (by date) AMOUNT".  I don't see any date.

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry about that. Thanks to Gordon for editing.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - you can put any date you like over there. This table shows the values for specified user ID (not shown as a column) with "ORDER BY date DESC" order (date also not shown as I thought it is not so important to describe my problem).

Comment: @Vogelek23 . . . I think you miss the point.  It is *your* question.  It is *your* data.  If you want constructive answers, you should endeavor to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - you're right, I have edited my question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've done it. After many checks and tests, I've finally used a very simple PHP code mixed with a much more simple MySQL queries:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM points_log WHERE user_id = '.(int)$_GET['u_id'].' ORDER BY date DESC'; // gets all records for specified user ID
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$previous = $db->sql_fetchrow($result); // processes the first row and prepares the data for further use

$after = $previous['after']; // gets the most recent value of points

while ($row=$db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
    $id = $previous['id']; // unique ID of the first row
    $amount = $previous['amount']; // amount from the first row
    $dir = ($previous['dir'] == 0) ? true : false; // direction of operation (0 = taken from, 1 = given to)

    if ($dir) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE points_log SET after='.$after.'+'.$amount.' WHERE id='.$row['id']; //adds points to the current value if they were subtracted previously
        $db->sql_query($sql);
        $after = $after+$amount; // sets new value of $after variable
    } else {
        $sql = 'UPDATE points_log SET after='.$after.'-'.$amount.' WHERE id='.$row['id']; //subtracts points from the current value if they were added previously
        $db->sql_query($sql);           
        $after = $after-$amount; // sets new value of $after variable
    }
    $previous = $row; // sets previous row with all its values as a current row (required to process all the rows one by one in a loop)
}
$db->sql_freeresult($result);
```

I'm now able to update the points log manually for every single user on his request. Below you can find the results:

```
===================================
 DATE     | AMOUNT |  DIR  | AFTER
===================================
 02-07-17 |   8    |   1   |   50
 01-07-17 |   3    |   0   |   42
 28-06-17 |   3    |   0   |   45
 14-11-15 |   8    |   1   |   48
 24-06-15 |   3    |   0   |   40
 22-05-15 |   3    |   0   |   43
===================================
```

Thanks to all!